# Issues with Stripe <-> Firebase integration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am really close to the finish line of making it work, Ive been struggling with this for weeks but there is one step remaining. So:

I have succesfully done all the steps required for the API, SDK, Webhooks, Firebase Stripe Extension, Firestore Rules, everything to work as it should be except this.

When a user register in my web app, a stripeID and stripe customerID (URL to Stripe dashboard for the customer) and metadata firebase ID is created in Firestore.

But later when the user subscribes through my stripe product inside my app, firestore does not update the user and a new customer is created with a new customerID in Stripe.

Now I have heard that the  that stripe  create could be the problem and thats why the checkout integration is not connected with the Firestore.

This is such a high priority for me, I would compensate alot for help here.